# Restrict Sub Items publishing on certain items

Tags: publishing

Occasionally one of our users will publish a near-root item (`/sitecore/content/Home/Daily/`) with Sub Items checked.  They're supposed to un-check the Sub Items option during this particular publish, but sometimes forget.  The problem is we have 200,000+ items and it takes a lot of time to process all those items.  I'd like to possibly restrict the Sub Items checkbox if they're on certain items.

I know that I can restrict Sub Items for a role, but the user also needs to publish Sub Items on other items.

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, it is closely related. And I believe any solution would need to take steps in this direction. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37691414/81631

Comment: Do you think that I would replace the publish button with a custom button that called a custom publish screen, one that didn't have a Sub Items option?

Comment: Something along those lines. But I do believe those checkboxes follow security permissions - so it might be possible to just override the bit of code that selects and displays them. And sprinkle a bit of Rules Engine on top.